# Best way to perform a convolution with a new vector for each image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, convolution

I try to figure out the best way to perform a kind of convolution.

I have a 3D matrix I = [N x M x P] and a 2D matrix S = [1 x 1 x K x P]. For each pth frame (third dimension) of my 3D matrix I want to return the valid convolution between I(:, :, p-K/2:p+K/2) and S(1, 1, :, p). Do you see a way to do this ?

In fact, in terms of computation the numbers of operation in very close to a standard convolution, the difference is that I need to change the second matrix for each frame...

This is the method I currently use:

```
% I = 3D matrix [N x M x P]
% S = Filter [1 x 1 x K x P] (K is an odd number)
% OUT = Result

[N, M, P] = size(I); % Data size
K = size(S, 3); % Filter length
win = (K-1)/2 ; % Window
OUT = zeros(size(I)); % Pre-allocation

for p = win+1:P-win
     OUT(:, :, p) = convn(I(:, :, p-win:p+win), S(1, 1, :, p), 'valid'); % Perform convolution
end
```

At the end we have the same number of operations than the standard convolution, the only difference is that the filter is different for each frame...

Any idea ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convolve a NxMxK sub-image with a 1x1xKx1 kernel, and then only take the valid part, which is an NxM image.

Let's look at this operation for a single (x,y) location. This 1D convolution, of which you only keep 1 value, is equivalent to the dot product of the sub-image and your kernel:

```
OUT(x,y,p) = squeeze(I(x,y,p-win:p+win))' * squeeze(S(1,1,:,p))
```

This you can vectorize across all (x,y) by reshaping the sub-image of I to a (N*M)xK matrix (the K is horizontal, S is a column vector).

Repeating this across all p is easiest to implement with a loop, as you do now. The alternative is to create a larger S where each column is shifted by one, so you can do a single dot product between tge two matrices. But that S is also espensive to create, presumably requires a loop too. I don't think that avoiding loops is that pressing any more in MATLAB (it's gotten a lot faster over the years) and the product itself is probably the most expensive part of the algorithm anyway.